# Getting #[object Object] when trying to get for attr for href

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I have a dynamically generated `ol li` list, and each `li` has a `label` with a `for` attribute.

Like this:

```
<ol id="altErrorCont" class="error-container">
    <li>
        <label class="error" for="dobMonth">Enter the month you were born</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label class="error" for="dobDay">Enter the day you were born</label>
```

On page load I want to wrap the labels with an `a` tag that contains an anchor for the `for` tag inside the label it wraps. This is what I want to happen:

```
<ol id="altErrorCont" class="error-container">
    <li>
        <a href="#dobMonth">
            <label class="error" for="dobMonth">Enter the month you were born</label>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#dobDay">
            <label class="error" for="dobDay">Enter the day you were born</label>
        </a>
```

I wrote this, but it's not working:

```
var labelFor = $("ol#altErrorCont li label").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("for");
});

$('ol#altErrorCont li > label').wrap('<a href="#'+ labelFor +'">');
```

It's returning `<a href="#[object Object]">` for each wrapped label. Can someone point me in the right direction or explain why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery's `.each()` method returns [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) object. When you use it in the string contcatenation, JavaScript calls `toString()` method on it. Since jQuery doesn't have its own `toString` method defined, it calls the method defined on the `Object.prototype` which returns `[object Object]`.

Here is how I would go about it:

```
var labelFor = $("ol#altErrorCont li label").each(function(){
    $(this).wrap('<a href="#'+ $(this).attr("for") +'">');
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @bunnycode, no problem, you can accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

[`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) just provides a means of iterating across a set of items. The value you're getting for `labelFor` would be the same as if you did

```
var labelFor = $("ol#altErrorCont li label");
```

If you want to wrap each `label` in a link, you can do some during the `each` loop.

```
$("ol#altErrorCont li label").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this); // Faster than always doing $(this)
  var label = $this.attr('for');
  $this.wrap('<a href="' + label + '">');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because "each" method return a **jQuery Object**, you can move this: 
`$('ol#altErrorCont li > label').wrap('<a href="#'+ labelFor +'">');`
inside of "each" method like this:

```
$(this).wrap('<a href="#'+ $(this).attr("for") +'">');
```